# Business Central: How to retrieve revenue gross (incl. VAT) from posted sales invoice lines table with Power BI?

Tags: powerbi-datasource, dynamics-business-central

I use Power BI to retrieve & visualize sales data from Business Central and so far I did not find any ways to:

- retrieve revenue gross on line level (per invoice and item number) of my posted sales invoice
- retrieve revenue gross on header level (invoice number) of my posted sales invoice
- retrieve VAT on line level (per invoice and item number) of my posted sales invoice, in order to calculate the revenue gross based on the revenue net

Anyone with an easy solution (i m sure there is one as it seems to be a fairly classic request)???

Best and let me know if you need any extra info,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

There's an 'Amount' and 'Amount Including VAT' column on the Sales Line table, those should give you everything you need.

Annoyingly these are not on the 'Power BI Sales List' query/web service as default, nor the Sales Lines page. If you're a BC developer you could write your own extension to publish a better query.

If not, there is a 'Sales Document Line Entity' page (6403) which includes them as 'Amount' and 'AmountInclVat'. This page is published by default (in SAAS at least) as the 'workflowSalesDocumentLines' web service and you can access it from PowerBI, you will probably want to also include workflowSalesDocuments, the two are related on a composite of Document Type AND DocumentNumber, so that's another challenge for you!

Comment: Well that wasn't as simple an answer as I would have hoped!